# How to hide the subsection in table of content

Tags: table-of-contents

In my project, I tried to hide the subsection from table of content by using the code `\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}` but it didn't worked

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc, vietnam}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.}

\begin{document}

\clearpage
\newpage
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\section{Linear Analysis}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\subsection{Definition}

\end{document}
```

How can I hide the subsection from table of content ? Thank you

Comment: Do you want to hide all subsections or just a single one?

Comment: Note that all sectional entries are actually written to the TOC no matter the value of `tocdepth`. It the executing of `\tableofcontents` that uses the value of `tocdepth`. Meaning it you only want to remove one subsection, the adjustment of `tocdepth` need to go into the `.toc` file.

Comment: You have`\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}` after `\tableofcontents` so it has no effect.

Comment: @daleif I don't follow what you meant, can you show the code in concrete ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I tried putting ``\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}``` right before ```\tableofcontents```, but it still didn't worked, so what should I do

Comment: When I move `\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}` up before `\tableofcontents` and remompile (maybe twice) I only see `Linear Analysis` in the toc. Without it I see both.

Comment: Can you please clarify if you want to remove all subsections or just a single subsection?

Comment: it will work (normally you set it in the preamble, but anywhere before `\tableofcontents` is OK)

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I want to remove all subsections

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have tried as you said
```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc, vietnam}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\begin{document}

\clearpage
\newpage
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\section{Linear Analysis}
\subsection{Definition}

\end{document}
```

and I still see the subsection in the table of content. I don't know why (I make my project on overleaf)

Comment: @PermQi You need `\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}`, like you write in your question. Not `\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}`

Comment: you have `\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}` so you have set it to 2

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I have tried 1 and 2 aswell, they have no effect

Comment: @PermQi Only use 1, don't use 2 at all.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't know if the issue may come from the fact that I compile my project on overleaf, since I have tried everything you guilded me but it still didn't worked

Comment: With just 1 it works fine: https://www.overleaf.com/read/psttwftqftgh#7227eb

Comment: no if you set it to 2 it will not work. it is nothing to do with overleaf

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz oh you're right, it worked, I still have no idea why while I have tried that way too and at that point it still didn't worked